# Calculate on the Fly While Still Allowing Input - Javascript API

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, calculated-columns

I have a Mysql table called `invoice_detais`  and I am using a PHP code generator PHPRUNER to retrieve, add, and edit data from my database. In the page that is used for adding a new record in `invoice_details`, I set the following Javascript event:

```
var ctrlPrice = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'Price');
var ctrlQuantity = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'Quantity');
var ctrlTotal = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'Total');

function func() {
    ctrlTotal.setValue(Number(ctrlPrice.getValue()) - Number(ctrlQuantity.getValue()));
};

ctrlPrice.on('keyup', func);
ctrlQuantity.on('change', func);
```

The quantity is  calculated on fly, but I can not edit the field, and sometimes I need it to be inserted manually without calculation. I mean to set this field to the auto-calculated value but also allow free input.

Please help.

Comment: @Feathercrown  Yhank you  very much for the correction  . Any idea about the poblem? please  i am newbie on this

Comment: You're welcome. I'm afraid I can't help you much on this one, though. Try posting a JSFiddle with the HTML and Javascript, maybe someone else will help.